# Foreign key to an arbitrary table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I need to store a foreign key in a table that doesn’t directly reference a table. I explain. Here I’d like to do something similar to *inheritance*, but it’s actually not. I have – for a given record in my table – two important fields: the *arbitrary* or *generic* key, and a field representing the type of what such a key would refer to. The idea is storing an integer, then regarding the type of the key, joining the corresponding table.

Is it even possible? What are the alternatives? I don’t want inheritance – I’m not using an *ODBMS*.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key in a "child" table must reference a single "parent" table. The parent must be specified at the time when you define your key. All rows in your child table must reference the same parent table - there can be no row-by-row differentiation.

Note, however, that a column does not need to be a foreign key in order to be used in a join. A foreign key constraint will prevent insertions of incorrect keys into the child table, and deal with deletions in a parent table by cascading into the child or throwing an error. If you do not care for this functionality, you could store your "foreign key" column normally, and use it in outer joins, like this:

```
select *
from child c
left outer join referenced1 r1 on c.fk = r1.pk AND c.code = 'first'
left outer join referenced2 r2 on c.fk = r2.pk AND c.code = 'second'
left outer join referenced3 r3 on c.fk = r3.pk AND c.code = 'third'
```

The above example assumes that your "foreign key" consists of two columns - the `fk` that indicates what row you reference, and `code` that indicates what table you want.

Answer (score 0):

`Multi-table foreign key` (or - to be more specific - "something like foreign key") in one column is possible if you resign from creating FK constraint and store related table name in another column. It'll work some way, unless you care about your data integrity. In fact, some people consider this as one of SQL antipatterns. :-)

Of course you can then create some trigger procedure and check every time if new/modified value exists in "related" table. It's not elegant though.

I think that the better way is to create foreign key in "related" tables (one table for every type):

```
main_table:
id
...(other columns)


table_type_first:
main_table_id
foreign_key_for_type_1
...(other columns)


table_type_second:
main_table_id
foreign_key_for_type_2
...(other columns)
```

It's also not brilliant, and maybe it's not exactly what you need (you don't have type column, "entity" type is dependent on existance of record in "type" tables), but it provides more data integrity.